# Angular POST not sending data to asp.net web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple asp.net webapi with a complex object. When i post the data from anuglar, the value is null in the api. Not sure what i am doing wrong h ere.

Can anyone please help?

Angular code:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

const results = this.http.post(url, this.searchCriteria, httpOptions)
                    .pipe(
                      map(response => {
                        const items = new Array();
                        console.log(`response: ${response}`);
                        return items;
                      }),
                      tap(
                        data => console.log(data),
                        error => console.log(error)
                      )
                    );
```

Thanks

Comment: What's `this.searchCriteria`?

Comment: Try to log `this.searchCriteria` first, and make sure someone is subscribing to the result Observable otherwise the api call won't be sent at all

Comment: Can you add your Controller Action method definition?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information than your method, but check if any of these recommendations helps:
Be sure you have data in searchCriteria with a console log.
If have undefined, check if you import the FormsModule into the app.module.ts 
Then check if it's a cors issue in your server side.